# I can't use snap packages, even if installed

Tags: gnome, snap, zsh

I installed Spotify, VS Code and Atom snap packages.
I used them a couple of days.
Today, I can't use them.
There are two different problems:

1. They aren't in Gnome Launcher with all other programs.
2. I can't use them starting them via cli because "command not found". I'm using zsh.

Comment: What does the output of `snap version` say?

Comment: @popey  `snap    2.29.4.2+17.10
snapd   2.29.4.2+17.10
series  16
ubuntu  17.10
kernel  4.13.0-22-generic`, thanks for your help

Comment: Look inside the `/snap/` folder. Various commands should be available there, is that true? What happens if you run one directly?

Comment: inside `/snap/` I have atom, bin, core, vscode. Inside `bin`, there are all executables. If I run `/snap/bin/atom`, atom start!
Nice! Thanks!
Now, why it doesn't work from my terminal, neither are there .desktop launchers in gnome?
Thanks for now

Comment: also `ll /snap/bin` lists installed snaps.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[SOLUTION to QUESTION1]

There is some kind of bug in I-do-not-know-where.
To temporally solve this, I had to copy `programname.desktop` from `/snap/programname/current/programname.desktop` to `/usr/share/applications` (with sudo) and then all was fixed: programname shows in the gnome menus.

[See more here](https://askubuntu.com/a/975153/396145)

[SOLUTION to QUESTION2]

The snap binary and desktop directories will not automatically be added to your environment variables. In order to solve this, I added the following line to `/etc/zsh/zprofile`:

```
emulate sh -c 'source /etc/profile'
```

[See more here](https://askubuntu.com/a/989485/396145)

Comment: Related `snapd` bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/snapd/+bug/1775340

Comment: `emulate sh -c 'source /etc/profile'` breaks oh-my-zsh themes for me

Comment: try `emulate sh -c 'source /etc/profile.d/apps-bin-path.sh'` as in the linked question

Answer (score 0):

use this to remove the package:

```
sudo snap remove name-package
```

use this to completely remove the directory where the packages are built (i.e, for example to remove the directory in which atom is built use : `sudo rm -rf ~/snap/name-package`; this will remove the directory and its child directories) and build them again:

```
sudo snap install name-package
```

Comment: **Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  :-)** *The last command is dangerous when run from the root directory!*  Could you [edit] and expand and provide exact details for the packages the OP is referring to?

Comment: @Fabby is this okay ?

Comment: Ok, i removed atom folder from ~/snap/atom . Sadly this doesn't solve my problem :(

Comment: build it again
if it still fails use 'mkdir name' to make a new directory and build atom there. Then use 'cd name' to access the directory and run atom from there.

Comment: @Nissaar Why do you use the term 'build'? I'm just installing it with `snap install`... I do not choose any folder!

Comment: in every snap tutorial ive seen 'build the snap.' And not 'install snap'. Ive seen that for travis, offlineimap etc... maybe im wrongly using the word. Did it work ?

Comment: I can't 'build' any snap in any folder. I just `snap install atom`. If I do `mkdir atom & cd atom & snap install atom` it makes no sense to me to do something like this.....

Comment: To have an idea where snaps are installed etcetera https://askubuntu.com/a/976039/396145

Answer (score 0):

an **alias** could be added to `.bash_aliases`

- `echo 'alias foosnap="/snap/bin/foo"' >> /root/.bash_aliases`
- `exec bash`

or a **symlink** could be added to `/usr/bin`

- `ln -s /snap/bin/foo /usr/bin/foosnap`

Answer (score 0):

this simple solution worked for me.

1. open your shell profile file `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc`
2. append `export PATH=$PATH:/snap/bin`
3. refresh profile changes `source ~/.bashrc` or `source ~/.zshrc`

enjoy your snaps !