# Is there a way to change the default colors in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, colors

Is there a way to change the default color from Orange? What I'm talking about is the close button on some programs, I actaully don't care for the color Orange, and I was wondering because I know Windows can, like whenever I'm moving programs from my Flash Drive to the computer or something like that, there's just something about the color Orange that's not pleasing to my eye, I wanna change it to blue and I'm running the latest version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Have you looked at changing the color theme?

Comment: I don't know where that is though or how to do that

Comment: I've posted an answer with a few images. See the link at the top of the answer to learn more about installing any of the 3 themes listed or the other 17 I didn't list.

Answer (score 4):

Install `gnome-tweak-tool`. Install various themes after doing research into what they look like and whether they're complete<sup>1</sup> and current.

- Using a complete theme is important so that even window decorations (such as the min/max/close buttons) are themed. Some themes are `gtk2`-only!
- Using a modern theme is important because there are several unmaintained themes that may not be compatible with your distro's current version.
- If you're new to the game, stay with themes from the standard software repositories<sup>2</sup>.
- Open `Tweaks`, which is what the `gnome-tweak-tool` appears as in the Dash, and choose from what you've installed. Changes are immediate.
- In the attached image, I've used Adwaita Dark.

[image: Change themes]

<sup>1</sup> The installation process for some themes may also provide `icon themes` so that an overall consistent look is available to you. Note that you may choose an icon theme using `Tweak`, otherwise the default remains.

<sup>2</sup> Note that if you look for themes in the Software Center, you may be offered `snap` versions as well as conventional versions. Please read up on `snaps` and their features.

- [Install as a snap or a package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/976036/install-as-a-snap-or-a-package)
- [What are the differences between snaps, appimage, flatpak and others?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866511/what-are-the-differences-between-snaps-appimage-flatpak-and-others)

Answer (score 1):

There are many themes available for Ubuntu that change your colours and appearance. This [article](http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/20-best-themes-for-ubuntu-in-2017) sums up the 20 best ones in 2017. From that article I've summarized the article with images of the top two favorites. I also added number 10 which you might like based on "blue" preference and it's similarity to default Ubuntu with a touch of Mac OS added..

### 1. Windows 10 Theme

If you admire the appearance of Redmond’s latest operating system, you can mimic the theme on your Ubuntu desktop. If you are looking for something really transforming and prevent unwanted attention, the Windows 10 unity themes might just be the one.

[image]

### 2. Macubuntu Theme

Straight from Redmond and to Cupertino. Apple’s **MacOS** has always been quite stunning and if you want your Ubuntu desktop looking like that, there is a theme available. The Macbuntu theme allows you to setup your desktop with wallpapers, shells, icons and fonts that will have you spotting a Mac on “not a Mac”.

[image]

### 10. Yosembiance

Yosembiance adds a gentle touch of smoothness and flatness to the typical Ambiance theme that ships with Ubuntu. So if you want a theme very much Ubuntu with just a touch of MacOS, Yosembiance is just the one. Yosembiance comes in Atomic, Kraken and Ubuntu all with options in Blue and Orange.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## How to change default orange scheme in Ubuntu 18.04

First of all there are two ways to do so:

Download an external shell theme from https://www.gnome-look.org and install theme.

However you may not find the color theme you want but this will at least change the orange color scheme (Also, not every shell theme changes the default orange color).

So there is another way. (Only suggested if you are good at CSS.)

The second way is that you need to edit the ubuntu.css file at:

> /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css
>   This file will allow you to change almost anything on you PC. From your login screen to shutdown menu. However it will take time to understand the ubuntu.css file but onceyou understand it you can customize your PC the way you like.

But remember to save a back-up of the original ubuntu.css file before you make any changes. Use the following command at the terminal to create a backup:

> sudo cp /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css.bak

Then, open the ubuntu.css file by the following command:

> sudo gedit /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css

Make the desired changes to the file and save. Remember that any change you make to this file will be applied globally i.e. to all user profiles. If you want to make changes to your account only then you need to edit the gnome-shell.css file at:

> /home/username/.themes/theme-folder/gnome-shell.css

After that open the gnome-tweak-tool and click Appearance. Select the shell-theme you made changes to. If you have any problems with the shell-theme menu in the gnome-tweak-tool see: [Why is Shell theme disabled in Gnome Tweak Tool?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/545741/why-is-shell-theme-disabled-in-gnome-tweak-tool)

And Reboot.

It worked brilliantly for me. Hope that also works for you!