# Are the snap package files isolated from normal package install?

Tags: apt, package-management, snap, deb, visual-studio-code

I have installed Visual studio code from a `.deb` package. So now that they provide a snap package, what would happen if install it as a snap package (without removing the former)?

I see from [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/976039/353387) answer that it is isolated file, so how where does it store extension files and configs? Are the configs isolated for snap files

Answer (score 0):

Applications installed as snap are indeed isolated, and will not interfere with the same application installed from a .deb package. Also user settings are isolated. User settings for a snap are stored under a directory "snap" in the user's home folder.

Comment: what about the `code` command in terminal?